# timezone in GetDate query is 12 hours out

Tags: sql, razor, timezone, webmatrix

I am using MS webmatrix and razor.

I have a query that uses the expression `CAST(GetDate() as INT)` to get the current date integer value. However, even though my server and PC are both set on GMT + 12 (Wellington, Auckland), the value returned is 12 hours out - and at 12.00 pm on my PC (and the server) it jumps ahead one day.

How do I trim 12 hours off the value, without having to set the time 12 hours wrong on my machines?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coercing a date directly into an INT looks quite wrong.

To properly get just the INTEGRAL value of the date, use DATEDIFF directly.

```
select cast(cast('20120301' as datetime) as int) -- 40967
select cast(cast('20120301 12:30' as datetime) as int) -- 40968, oh noes!
select datediff(d,0,'20120301') -- 40967
select datediff(d,0,'20120301 12:30') -- 40967, yes!
```

Comment: OK, but how do i remove the actual 20120301 bit? I want this to automatically update with the current date by itself. Or are the bits in red above bits I leave out and you only put them in to show me what to do? Sorry, I'm not clued up on this!

Comment: do I replace the '20120301' with 'GetDate() ?